# File in Use after WebClient download

Tags: c#, webclient

I've downloaded a file and tried to delete it based on its size after doing so, however, it says  the file is in use.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(sb.ToString()), sbFileLocation.ToString());

 if (new FileInfo(sbFileLocation.ToString()).Length == 0)
            {
                File.Delete(sbFileLocation.ToString());
            }
```

As you can see, File.Delete raises an exception, stating that the file is in use.

Is there some way to close it and then delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DownloadFileAsync(Uri, String, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFileAsync_System_Uri_System_String_)

> Downloads, to a local file, the resource with the specified URI. This
>   method does not block the calling thread.

What this means is the file may (or may not) be completely downloaded before you call `File.Delete(sbFileLocation.ToString());`. This is a typical race condition and fully explains your error.

> This method downloads the resource at the URI specified by in the
>   address parameter. When the download completes successfully, the
>   downloaded file is named fileName on the local computer. The file is
>   downloaded asynchronously using thread resources that are
>   automatically allocated from the thread pool. **To receive
>   notification when the file is available, add an event handler to the
>   DownloadFileCompleted event.**

You either need to use the [`DownloadFileCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) event, the synchronous [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) method or `await` the Task based [`WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) method

Comment: I see, but now that I changed to the Synchronous task, it is not downloading the file that was being downloaded Asynchronously and thus raising a File Not Found exception.

Comment: @JohnnyGuitar so you are using `WebClient.DownloadFile` and the file is not downloading, is it giving you an error, or is it just taking a long time?

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file'.
It's weird, since it was working with Async, just not being able to actually delete it.

Comment: @JohnnyGuitar on which line is it giving that error?

Comment: Oh!!! So sorry!
I tried using messagebox on the same file afterwards, thus raising the error, because the file was already deleted!
thanks alot, you're the man!